# LINQ Sum with GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

(Not sure if I even need GroupBy)

My (simplified) tables:

`Products` (ProductID, Name, Code)
`Invoices` (InvoiceID, Number, IsPaid)
`Invoices_Products` (InvoiceID, ProductID, Quantity, Price) - the many-to-many linking table

I need to show a list of Invoices_Products of paid Invoices grouped by the Product Code which sums (Quantity*Price).

The code that I first use to get a collection that I can bind to the UI:

```
IEnumerable<Invoices_Products> invoices_products = db.Invoices_Products
.Where(ip => ip.Invoice.IsPaid).DistinctBy(m => m.Product.Code);
```

I then iterate through this to bind it to the UI:

```
List<BindableInvoiceProduct> bindableInvoiceProducts = 
new List<BindableInvoiceProduct>();

foreach (var item in invoices_products)
{
    decimal salesValue = db.Invoices_Products.Where(ip => ip.Invoice.IsPaid 
    && ip.Product.Code == item.Product.Code).Sum(m => (m.Price * m.Quantity));

    bindableInvoiceProducts.Add(new BindableInvoiceProduct()
    {
        A = item.A,
        B = item.B,
        SalesValue = salesValue.ToString()
    });
}
```

(The `DistinctBy` method there is from morelinq)

Why does this not total correctly?

**edit:**

Some data:

Product - ProductID = 1, Name = 123, Code = A
Product - ProductID = 2, Name = 456, Code = A
Invoice - InvoiceID = 1, Number = INV123, IsPaid = True
Invoices_Products - InvoiceID = 1, ProductID = 1, Quantity = 10, Price = 100
Invoices_Products - InvoiceID = 1, ProductID = 2, Quantity = 10, Price = 200

Expected result:

Code = A, SalesValue = 3000

Comment: What do you mean it "does not total correctly"? Gives us input, expected output (and an explanation), and current output.

Comment: If you are summing up the total of invoices paid...why would you then remove some of these invoices with distinct?  Seems to me you are trimming off paid invoices from your total.

Comment: They need to be displayed grouped by the same Product Code, the total needs to be of all the products on that invoice with that code - a sum of all of their (Quantity*Price)

Comment: @It'sNotALie, my bad, it is late, I will edit my question with some sample data

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but using the invoices_products as starting table, will mix-up all (paid) invoices? And you group on product code thru all invoices and add price*quanitity of all product codes thru all invoices? Did you expect per invoice a producecode => quantity*price?

Answer (score 1):

```
from invoice in invoices
where invoice.IsPaid
from xr in invoice.InvoiceProducts
group xr.Quantity * xr.Price by xr.Product.Code into g
select new {Code = g.Key, SalesValue = g.Sum()};
```

If you want per invoice, then:

```
from invoice in invoices
where invoice.IsPaid
from xr in invoice.InvoiceProducts
group xr.Quantity * xr.Price
  by new {Code = xr.Product.Code, Invoice = invoice }
  into g
select new {
  Code = g.Key.Code,
  Invoice = g.Key.Invoice,
  SalesValue = g.Sum()};
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description I would have written:

```
var bindableInvoiceProducts = db.Invoices_Products
    .Where(ip => ip.Invoice.IsPaid)
    .GroupBy(ip => ip.Product.Code, 
             (code, ips) => new BindableInvoiceProduct()
                {
                    Code = code,
                    SalesValue = ips.Sum(ip => (ip.Price*ip.Quantity))
                })
    .ToList();
```

Is that, what you need? What is item.A and item.B in your code?